# Twilio : Same phone number needs to be able to go to different versions of our application

Tags: twilio

When we release a new version of our application, we cant add new phone numbers in order for twilio to call back to the correct urls.  Is there a way to send the version information when we tell twilio to make a call and have that injected into the callback urls?

phone number 555-5555 points to voice request url

https://myapplication.com/1.0/voicerequest/IncomingCall

When I release a new version, I need to find a way for twilio to callback to v2.0 for a 2.0 version call and to 1.0 for a 1.0 version call.

https://myapplication.com/2.0/voicerequest/IncomingCall

I need to these to be for the same phone number since we cant be asking our clients to learn a new phone number every time they upgrade to a new version of our application.

Answer (score 0):

Will a given user always use one and only one version of the software at at time? For example, once the upgrade to V2, they'll never use V1 again?

If so, you could attach a version to *their* inbound phone number. So when they call from a number you have on file, you can look up which version of the software to use on the fly. If they call from an unknown number.. maybe you could ask what version to use or potentially ask them to key in their regular number?

If someone could use V2 today and V1 tomorrow, it's quite a bit more challenging.. separate phone numbers on your side is the only solution I can think of offhand.

Answer (score 0):

You can also let this current number to the most up to date version (V2 currently but maybe V3 in some months) and create another number for previous version.

So users will automatically have the updated version but they can fallback on previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Your twilio handler can do this.

You can maintain seperate handler file for each version and a main handler to redirect. When an incoming call hits the main handler url of your twilio application, Redirect the call to the latest version's handler file. You just need to add a handler every time you update your version.